# How to get rid of right-click menu "new TextWrangler document with selection" on Mac

Tags: macos, uninstall, textwrangler

I installed TextWrangler. Then I did not want it anymore and moved the app to the Trash. But the right click menu remained. I cannot figure out how to remove it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These *Services* are declared in `TextWrangler.app/Contents/Info.plist`. You should be good once you empty the Trash and log out and back in, or restart your computer.

---

To hide them in the meantime, open *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*, select *Services*, and uncheck the item *New TextWrangler document with selection* in the list.